# Converting string from memorystream to binary[] contains leading crap

Tags: c#, stream

--Edit with more bgnd information--

A (black box) COM object returns me a string.
A 2nd COM object expects this same string as byte[] as input and returns a byte[] with the processed data.
This will be fed to a browser as downloadable, non-human-readable file that will be loaded in a client side stand-alone application.

so I get the string inputString from the 1st COM and convert it into a byte[] as follows

```
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
bf.Serialize(ms, inputString);
obj = ms.ToArray();
```

I feed it to the 2nd COM and read it back out.
The result gets written to the browser.

```
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename="test.dat");
Response.BinaryWrite(obj);
```

The error occurs in the 2nd COm because the formatting is incorrect.
I went to check the original string and that was perfectly fine. I then pumped the result from the 1st com directly to the browser and watched what came out. It appeared that somewhere along the road extra unreadable characters are added. What are these characters, what are they used for and how can I prevent them from making my 2nd COM grind to a halt?

The unreadable characters are of this kind:

NUL/SOH/NUL/NUL/NUL/FF/FF/FF/FF/SOH/NUL/NUL/NUL etc

Any ideas?

**--Answer--**
Use

```
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(theString)
```

rather then

```
BinaryFormatter.Serialize()
```

Comment: When you say "this crap", does the 'this' refer to anything in your post, or are you saying that there's something else there but you can't paste it or describe it?

Comment: D'oh. Some comments are anything than polite ;-)

Comment: if that's the worst (word) you encounter in your life, you got nothing to worry about ;)

Comment: The output you pasted is exactly what you expect from binary serialization.

Comment: This must have been my most chaotic post thus far..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, with your updated information: your 2nd COM object expects binary data, but you want to create that binary data from a string. Does it treat it as plain binary data?

My guess is that something is going to reverse this process on the client side. If it's eventually going to want to reconstruct the data as a string, you need to pick the right encoding to use, and use it on both sides. UTF-8 is a good bet in most cases, but *if* the client side is just going to write out the data to a file and use it as an XML file, you need to choose the appropriate encoding based on the XML.

You said before that the first few characters of the string were just `"<foo>"` (or something similar) - does that mean there's no XML declaration? If not, choose UTF-8. Otherwise, you should look at the XML declaration and use that to determine your encoding (again defaulting to UTF-8 if the declaration doesn't specify the encoding).

Once you've got the right encoding, use Encoding.GetBytes as mentioned in earlier answers.

Comment: There is indeed no declaration and I fooled around a bit to check all outcomes and UTF-8 seems to work fine.
After that GetBytes was indeed the way to go.
Your answer was the most comprehensible. Go go gadget skeet

Answer (score 2):

BinaryFormatter is almost certainly not what you want to use.

If you just need to convert a string to bytes, use [Encoding.GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getbytes.aspx) for a suitable encoding, of course. UTF-8 is usually correct, but check whether the document specifies an encoding.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the point of BinarySerialization.

For starters, what Type is formulaXml?

Binary serialization will compact that into a machine represented value, NOT XML!  The content will look like:

```
    ÿÿÿÿ          AIronScheme, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, Public
```

Perhaps you should be looking at the XML serializer instead.

**Update:**

You want to write out some XML as a 'content-disposition' stream.

To do this, do something like:

```
byte[] buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(formulaXml);
Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
```

That should work like you hoped (I think).

Comment: "I convert a string (formulaXml) to binary as follows"
The name of the string ends in XML, but it is just a string

Comment: But why???? Why are you doing this? Just write the string!  I dont understand why you are involving any form of serialization here.

Comment: Ok, I see why you want it binary, to use 'content-disposition'.  Will update my answer.

Comment: well actually, in the bigger scheme it is because my site has to use two seperate COM objects. One I feed some info in and receive an xml file back. A second one that does some transformations on this xml and encrypts it in my company's encryption method (don't ask, can't help it)

Comment: Encoding.Default is almost certainly *not* correct - why would you want a client's browser to see something encoded with the *server's* default encoding?

Comment: Then this binary data gets streamed to the client on the browser so they can read it into their client side software that uses this file.

Comment: So why are you writing the plain binary back to the browser here?

Comment: The client's browser isn't going to see it, it's going to download it so it can be loaded in a client side application.

Comment: @Jon: That was just an example. I have no idea what the XML is encoded in.

Comment: @Jon: hence my 'do something like'

Comment: Ok, there is a lot of confusion going on here. I'm going to edit my original post some.

Answer (score 1):

The `BinaryFormatter`'s job is to convert the objects into some opaque serialisation format that can only be understood by another `BinaryFormatter` at the other end.

(Just about to mention `Encoding.GetBytes` as well, but Jon beat me to it.)

You'll probably want to use System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes().

Answer (score 0):

Is the crap in the beginning two bytes long?

This could be the byte order mark of a Unicode encoded string.

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark